# Induction profe with geometrical cycle

Tags: induction

I have an equation:

$$x(n+1)=5x(n)+4\\x(0)=0$$

For my task I need to provide simple equation for $x(n)$, so I go for this method:

1. I make some changes in equation:
   $$x(n+1)=5x(n)+5-1\\
   x(n+1)=5(x(n)+1)-1$$
2. I use temp function $$y(n)=x(n)+1\\
   x(n+1)=5y(n)-1\\
   5y(n)=x(n+1)+1$$
3. I calculate first few values for $y(n)$ for $n=0$: $$5y(0)=x(1)+1=1$$ {$x(1)=4$, from previous equation}
   for $n=1$: $$5y(1)=x(2)+1=5$$
   for $n=2$: $$5y(2)=x(3)+1=25$$

So I see that $y(n)$ is geometrical cycle, so from theory of geometrical cycle:

- equation for $n+1$ element will be: $$y(n+1)=y(n)\cdot q - q=5,$$ because every next element is $5$ times bigger so: $$y(n+1)=y(n)\cdot5$$
- equation for n element will be y(n)=y(0)*q^(n-1) {y(0) was 5}, so y(n)=5^n

But this is something I guess on base of few values so I need to prove: $y(n)=5^n$

Induction - step 1 - for $n=1$
$$y(1)=5^1\\
L=5\\
R=5\\
L=R$$
It's correct

Induction - step 2 - for $n=k$
$$y(k)=5^k$$

Induction - step 3 - for $n=k+1$
$$y(k+1)=5^(k+1)$$

$$L=y(k+1)\text{ (from equation for } n+1\text{-th element }y(k+1)=y(k)\cdot 5\text{)}\\
L=5y(k)\\
R=5^(k+1)\\
\text{Both sides are divided by 5}\\
L=y(k)\\
R=5^k\\
L=R$$

And it looks fine for me but, last time I solve this it was wrong because "I tried to prove one thing using this same thing" which is wrong, and I am not sure if this one is correct, cna I use first step in "step 3"?

p.s. sorry for my english :)

**EDIT**
I made some changes according to user160738 advices, please can you check is it correct now?
[Link to PDF](http://speedy.sh/MqAD9/requrence-equation.pdf)

Comment: The following will sure help you: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: @5xum, thanks. i was in the middle of editing.

Comment: @abel Is that sarcasm?

Comment: @5xum, not at all. my latexing and formatting is not that good. i appreciate your effort.

Comment: x(n+1)=5x(n)+4 --> x(n+1)+1=5(x(n)+1) --> y(n+1)=5y(n). Some of your steps are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a big gap in your arguments is that in your step 3 you observed some values of $y(n)$ and *conjectured* that $y(n)$ is a geometric sequence.

Then you assumed it to be geometric sequence and $y(n)$ has to have certain expression ***when you assumed it to be in that form***.

So you assumed what you wanted prove and proved it again (circling argument).

Your induction step seems fine, so I will just add some clarification for your conjecture:

In first step you found that

$$ x(n+1)=5(x(n)+1)-1$$

Let's define $y(n)$ as you defined it to be.

Then $$y(n)=x(n)+1$$

and we have

$$ x(n+1)=5(x(n)+1)-1 \implies x(n+1)+1=5(x(n)+1) \implies y(n+1)=5y(n)$$

Now the answer follows immediately using induction

Comment: Ok that's clarify why my approach was wrong, please check this pdf, I made some corrections, is it good now?
[link to pdf](http://speedy.sh/MqAD9/requrence-equation.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Equations like this are best solved by rewriting them as difference equations: 
$$
a_k = 5 a_{k-1} +4\\
a_{k-1} = 5 a_{k-2} +4\\
\Delta a_k = 5 \Delta a_{k-1} = 5^2 \Delta a_{k-2} = \ldots 5^{k-1} \Delta a_1
$$
You know the boundary value, so you need to make one little last step to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment I am too lazy to have a good look at your work, so just an advice to make things easyer. If we just write down the $x_n$ then we see:

- $x_0=0$
- $x_1=4$
- $x_2=5.4+4$
- $x_3=5.5.4+5.4+4$
- $x_4=5.5.5.4+5.5.4+5.4+4$

et cetera.

Don't you recognize something a nice pattern here? Based on it you can find an expression of $x_n$ and you can make things complete by proving that $x_{n+1}=5.x_n+4$ by means of induction.

Comment: Hi, I havea already profed that earlier in this task, but goal is to remove x(n+1), and have simple equation for x(n), and i get it:
x_1 (n+1)=5y(n)-1
y(n)=5^n
after proving those upper I have:
x_1 (n+1)=5*5^n-1
x_1 (n+1)=5^(n+1)-1
x_1 (n)=5^n-1
But of course I need proof for y(n)=5^n, can you take a look on this: [pdf](http://speedy.sh/MqAD9/requrence-equation.pdf)

Comment: If you are looking for a closed form of $x_n$ then I don't see what $y_n$ is needed for. It is evident that $x_{n}=4\left(5^{n-1}+\cdots+5^{1}+1\right)$.
Multiplying both sides with $4=5-1$ gives $4x_{n}=4\left(5^{n}-1\right)$
so that $x_{n}=5^{n}-1$.

Comment: Ok I don't really get this one, but is my solution in this linked pdf wrong somehow?

Comment: The way you handle it in your pdf is okay. Btw, $(5-1)(5^{n-1}+\cdots+5^{1}+5^{0})=(5^{n}+5^{n-1}+\cdots+5^{1})-(5^{n-1}+5^{n-2}+\cdots+5^{0})=5^{n}-5^{0}$. Maybe you missed that.

Answer (score 0):

look for a particular solution of $x(n+1)= 5x(n) + 4$ in the form $x(n) = A.$
$A$ is determined by $A = 5A + 4$ so $A = -1$ now the solution to the homogeneous equation $x(n+1) = 5x(n)$ is $x(n) = C5^n$ and the general solution is $$x(n) = C5^n -1$$ and $C$ gets fixed by requiring $x(0) = 0$ which give you $C=1.$ so the solution is $$x(n) = 5^n - 1$$